# How to set an ImageButton background color to a specific color of a theme that could be adapted to the night mode?

Tags: android, background, android-imagebutton

I want to find a way to set the background color of an ImageButton to a color that I defined in my themes and which changes with day or night mode.

Is this possible?

Here is the color that I want (colorPrimary) in the themes file:

```
<item name="colorPrimary">@color/blue_900</item>
```

Thank you very much.

Bapt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Material Design guidelines (see [here](https://material.io/develop/android/theming/dark)),

1. In `styles.xml`, inherit from a `DayNight` theme.

```
    <style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight">
        ...
        ...
    </style>
```

2. Create a new `colors.xml` file under the `values-night` directory.

[image]

[image]

3. In `values\colors.xml`,

```
    <color name="primary_color">{your-light-theme-color-here}</color>
```

In `values-night\colors.xml`

```
    <color name="primary_color">{your-dark-theme-color-here}</color>
```

4. In `styles.xml`,

```
    <style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary_color</item>
        ...
    </style>
```

5. Set this theme in your `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
    <application
        ...
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApp">
    </application>
```

I feel this is the most guideline-appropriate and efficient way.

Answer (score 2):

First, give the theme a custom value to your theme in the manifest:

```
        <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:theme="@style/MyMCNoactionBar">...
```

Then customize your theme in style.xml:

```
<style name="MyMCNoactionBar" 
parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentTransitions" 
tools:targetApi="21">true</item>

    <!-- Colors -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/colorPrimaryVariant</item>

    <item name="colorSecondary">@color/colorSecondary</item>
    <item 
name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/colorSecondaryVariant</item>

    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/colorBackground</item>
    <item name="colorSurface">@color/colorSurface</item>
    <item name="colorError">@color/colorError</item>

    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/colorOnPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/colorOnSecondary</item>
    <item name="colorOnBackground">@color/colorOnBackground</item>
    <item name="colorOnSurface">@color/colorOnSurface</item>
    <item name="colorOnError">@color/colorOnError</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor" 
tools:targetApi="21">@color/colorPrimaryVariant</item>

    <item name="android:textColor">@color/textColor</item>
    <item name="android:divider">@color/divider</item>
    <item 
name="colorControlHighlight">@color/colorControlHighlight</item>

    <item 
name="colorBackgroundFloating">@color/alertDialogBackgroundColor</item>                                  
<!--AlertDialogBackgroundColor-->
    <item name="android:colorBackgroundFloating" 
tools:targetApi="23">@color/alertDialogBackgroundColor</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/controlNormal</item>
</style>
```

Then in your main class, check the value that the user has for the dark or light theme and apply it to the theme:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 

    setDayNight(); //Note: before setContentView
    setContentView(R.layout.main_lauout);
}

private void setDayNight() {

    boolean isDark =this.getSharedPreferences("setting", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
                   .getBoolean("isDark", false);
    if (isDark) {
        AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);
        
AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
    }
}
```

Right-click on the res/ values/colors directory and (new) and (Values Resource File)

Set the file name to colors

And

set name the directory to values-night
Click OK

Put your light colors in colors.xml:

```
    <color name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</color>
<color name="colorPrimaryVariant">#303F9F</color>

<color name="colorSecondary">#536DFE</color>
<color name="colorSecondaryVariant">#212C75</color>

<color name="colorBackground">#FFFFFF</color>
<color name="colorSurface">#FFFFFF</color>
<color name="colorError">#B00020</color>

<color name="colorOnPrimary">#FFFFFF</color>
<color name="colorOnSecondary">#FFFFFF</color>
<color name="colorOnBackground">#FFFFFF</color>
<color name="colorOnSurface">#000000</color>
<color name="colorOnError">#FFFFFF</color>
<color name="textColor">#000000</color>
<color name="colorAccent">#536DFE</color>
<color name="colorAccentTwo">#536DFE</color>
<color name="divider">#DDcccccc</color>
<!--ImageButton-->
<!--set your light color Instead @color/blue_900 -->
<color name="imageButtonColor">@color/blue_900</color>
```

put night color in colors.xml(night)

```
<color name="colorPrimary">#212121</color>                                      
<!--actionBarColor-->
<color name="colorPrimaryVariant">#000000</color>                               
<!---->

<color name="colorSecondary">#21E600</color>                                    
<!--radioButtonCircleCheckedColor-->
<color name="colorSecondaryVariant">#03DAC6</color>

<color name="colorBackground">#303030</color>                                   
<!--background-->
<color name="colorSurface">#121212</color>
<color name="colorError">#CF6679</color>

<color name="colorOnPrimary">#000000</color>
<color name="colorOnSecondary">#FF26FF00</color>                                
<!--color drawable into fab-->
<color name="colorOnBackground">#FFFFFF</color>                                 <!--ActionBarTitle-->
<color name="colorOnSurface">#FFFFFF</color>                                    <!--circle Radio Button-->
<color name="colorOnError">#000000</color>
<color name="textColor">#FFFFFF</color>                                         
<!--TextColor-->
<color name="colorAccent">#FF26FF00</color>
<color name="colorAccentTwo">#28B133</color>
<color name="divider">#000000</color>
<!--ImageButton-->
<!--set your color dark Instead #424242-->
<color name="imageButtonColor">#424242</color>
```

And in your layout, select the following value for the color of the imageButton:

```
   <ImageButton
app:backgroundTint="@color/imageButtonColor"
    />
```

The above method is the suggested method of Android, but you can also do the following method (if you just want to change the color of a view, the following method is better):

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_lauout);

    boolean isDark = getSharedPreferences("setting", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
                   .getBoolean("isDark", false);


    if (isDark)
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21)
        findViewById(R.id.imageButton).getBackground().setTint(getResources().getColor(R.color.yourDarkColor));
```

}

Comment: This has been really helpful, thank you very much, even if I didn't need so much examples of colors! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Now, Android provides a night theme you can edit at the default if you know that,

but I was using this way before a years where I should create a new style (theme) :

** your style or theme file : **

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<!-- Base application theme. -->

<style name="Theme.Test" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Primary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
</style>

<!-- the Night theme -->
<style name="myNightTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Night brand color. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/black</item>
</style>

</resources>
```

in the second theme you can change whatever colors you want inside it

and you can use this code in your `Activity` to change theme to the second one :

```
setTheme(R.style.myNightTheme);
```